# Button list with one button per page

Tags: android, android-layout, wear-os

I would like to create some sort of menu on Android Wear. I would like use some buttons in "list". One button only should be visible, but user can swipe up to see next button. But I'm not sure how to create this sort of menu. Is it possible through `layout.xml`?

Example:
[image]

Comment: you can use view pager for this. By default view pager works swiping left and right. but you can customize to top and bottom. See this link https://gist.github.com/deepak786/c50829f0a7861dcc1036

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [2D picker](https://developer.android.com/design/wear/structure.html#2DPicker) pattern. In your case, you will create a 2D picker with only one column. You can also look at Google's [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/2d-picker.html) of how to create a 2D picker.